# [Flutter][Dart] Why do I get error of undefined name "index" after defining under void(savedata)?

Tags: flutter, dart, undefined

This project is a shopping app and the function I am trying to achieve with the following code is the add to cart function. I got an "Undefined Name" error for integer "index" despite defining it in the void(saveData). I'm very new to coding so I'm thinking there might be something I've overlooked.

The error is the highlighted line in this image here:
[highlighted line of undefined name error][1]

The line of code where I defined "index" is in the following image:
[defining "index" in void][2]

The full code for this dart file is as follows:

```
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:MyShoppingApp/provider/CartProvider.dart';
import 'package:MyShoppingApp/db/cart_database.dart';
import 'package:MyShoppingApp/model/cart.dart';
import 'model/products_repository.dart';


class ProductDetailsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/user-products';
   ProductDetailsPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key); //const
  DBHelper dbHelper = DBHelper();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //get particular productId using the ModalRoute class
    final productId = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String;
    print(productId);
    //use Provider package to find out ID by accessing method declared in Product()
    final loadedProduct = ProductsRepository().findById(productId);
  
    //List<bool> clicked = List.generate(10, (index) => false, growable: true);
      final cart = Provider.of<CartProvider>(context);
      void saveData(int index) {
        dbHelper
            .insert(
          CartItem(
            id: index,
            title: loadedProduct.name,
            price: loadedProduct.price.toDouble(),
            quantity: ValueNotifier(1),
            image: loadedProduct.image,
          ),
        )
            .then((value) {
          cart.addTotalPrice(loadedProduct.price.toDouble());
          cart.addCounter();
          print('Product Added to cart');
        }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
          print(error.toString());
        });
      }

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.orange[50],
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange[900],
        title: const Text("Product details "),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back_ios_outlined,
            color: Colors.black,
            semanticLabel: 'back to home',
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
      ),
        body:
        SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
               SizedBox(
                 height: 300,
                 width: double.infinity,
                 child: Image.network(
                   loadedProduct.image,
                   fit: BoxFit.cover,
                 ),
               ),
              const SizedBox(height: 10),
              Text(
                '\$${loadedProduct.price}',
                style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  fontSize: 20,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: Colors.blueGrey.shade900),
                  onPressed: () {
                    saveData(index);
                  },
                  child: const Text('Add to Cart')),
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                width: double.infinity,
                child: Text(
                  loadedProduct.description,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  softWrap: true,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Any form of help would be so greatly appreciated, I have been struggling with this error for very long. Thank you!

Edit:
CartProvider dart file code:

````
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../model/cart.dart';
import 'package:MyShoppingApp/db/cart_database.dart';

class CartProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  DBHelper dbHelper = DBHelper();
  int _counter = 0;
  int _quantity = 1;
  int get counter => _counter;
  int get quantity => _quantity;

  double _totalPrice = 0.0;
  double get totalPrice => _totalPrice;

  List<CartItem> cart = [];

  Future<List<CartItem>> getData() async {
    cart = await dbHelper.getCartList();
    notifyListeners();
    return cart;
  }

  void _setPrefsItems() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setInt('cart_items', _counter);
    prefs.setInt('item_quantity', _quantity);
    prefs.setDouble('total_price', _totalPrice);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void _getPrefsItems() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _counter = prefs.getInt('cart_items') ?? 0;
    _quantity = prefs.getInt('item_quantity') ?? 1;
    _totalPrice = prefs.getDouble('total_price') ?? 0;
  }

  void addCounter() {
    _counter++;
    _setPrefsItems();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void removeCounter() {
    _counter--;
    _setPrefsItems();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  int getCounter() {
    _getPrefsItems();
    return _counter;
  }

  void addQuantity(int id) {
    final index = cart.indexWhere((element) => element.id == id);
    cart[index].quantity!.value = cart[index].quantity!.value + 1;
    _setPrefsItems();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void deleteQuantity(int id) {
    final index = cart.indexWhere((element) => element.id == id);
    final currentQuantity = cart[index].quantity!.value;
    if (currentQuantity <= 1) {
      currentQuantity == 1;
    } else {
      cart[index].quantity!.value = currentQuantity - 1;
    }
    _setPrefsItems();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void removeItem(int id) {
    final index = cart.indexWhere((element) => element.id == id);
    cart.removeAt(index);
    _setPrefsItems();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  int getQuantity(int quantity) {
    _getPrefsItems();
    return _quantity;
  }

  void addTotalPrice(double productPrice) {
    _totalPrice = _totalPrice + productPrice;
    _setPrefsItems();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void removeTotalPrice(double productPrice) {
    _totalPrice = _totalPrice - productPrice;
    _setPrefsItems();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  double getTotalPrice() {
    _getPrefsItems();
    return _totalPrice;
  }
}```

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8OGs.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYE10.png
````

Comment: You have not defined 'Index'. saveData function expects you to pass index

Comment: There is no `index` variable within the scope, It would be easier if you provide more snippet that is depended on this widget structure.

Comment: @Md.KamrulAmin Firstly, thank you for your reply! Sorry but I'm not too sure what you mean by passing index. I'm not very familiar with how to implement this cart function and I followed this tutorial [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/building-shopping-cart-flutter/#create-basic-shopping-cart-ui) and referenced index the same way he did in his code. Thank you for your help though, it really means a lot to me

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Thank you so much for your help! I actually followed a tutorial [from here](https://blog.logrocket.com/building-shopping-cart-flutter/#create-basic-shopping-cart-ui) - I can't really attach all the code where "index" is referenced because it's too long but most of it should be under the above link. Thank you so much for your help! Here is a snippet of code from CartProvider: `Cart(
     id: index,
     productId: index.toString(),
     quantity: ValueNotifier(1),
     unitTag: products[index].unit,
     image: products[index].image,` (I can't comment everything sorry!)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any list to represent that index so, in your  ElevatedButton instead of using index could use an other number. so there is a workaround for that and that is use random number for that.

```
ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: Colors.blueGrey.shade900),
                  onPressed: () {
                    saveData(Random().nextInt(1000));
                  },
                  child: const Text('Add to Cart')),
```

Comment: Thank you for you help! I have tried that but I got an error saying: Instance member 'id' can't be accessed using static access. Might you know what that means? Thank you again, I really appreciate the help so much

Comment: could you please include your CartProvider class? and also tell me what type  loadedProduct is?

Comment: I've added the CartProvider class code above! loadedProduct is type:Product
Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

The `body` is returning a `ListView.builder`, and index can be get from there,

```dart
    body: ListView.builder(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 8.0),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: products.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Card(
```

The original  code can be found [here](https://github.com/timelessfusionapps/shopping_cart_app/blob/main/lib/screens/product_list.dart#L120)

Comment: Thank you. However, I get the following error: The getter 'length' isn't defined for the type 'Product'. Which is kind of weird since I don't get an error when I use `itemCount: provider.cart.length,` in my CartPage. I thought `int get length;` is already defined in list.dart. Any idea why this could be so? Thanks again, appreciate it so much man!